# Having problems with responsive widths

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I tried to make a search block that need to be looking like [this](http://2015.uploaded.fresh.co.il/2015/05/21/17298521.png):

Now i want when someone will resize the window, the search button will still be in the same line, so i did:

CSS:

```
.search {
    background-color: #23507c;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 92%
}
#searchButton {
    width: 8%; 
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
<span style="width: 100%;padding:0;margin:0;">
<input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="search for diamonds" />
<button type="submit" id="searchButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
Search</button>
</form>
</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kL1m9a8x/15/

What i try to do, is to insert the input and the button to a span that take the width of the blue block execept the glypicon, and than give to the input 80% from the parent element and the button have 20%, but its not working.
 The line break and the button found in the next line... even when the window is big...

Comment: Please check the opening and closing of span element. Especisally one which has end between </form> and </div>

Comment: Both elements has `width+padding+border > 100%`.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid! Check it [here](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: captainsac what to check with them? , @panther , i set they padding to 0, didnt help: https://jsfiddle.net/kL1m9a8x/16/, Liam thanks i fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#search{    
    position: relative;
    margin: 5%;
}


.search-inner{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #23507c;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.search-item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
.search-item-1{
    width: 82%;
    color: #fff;
}
.search-item-1 .glyphicon{
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 10px;    
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
        transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
.search-item-2{
    text-align: right;
}
input,
button{
    border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
input{    
     background-color: #23507c;
     color: #fff;
     padding-left: 35px;  
     width: 100%;
}
button{
   width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="search">
 <form action="search.php" method="POST">
     <div class="search-inner">
     <div class="search-item search-item-1">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
         <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="search for diamonds" required />
     </div>
         <div class="search-item search-item-2">
         <button type="submit" id="searchButton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
       </button>
     </div>
     </div>
 </form>
 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, work great, can you please add an explaination of what you did here? for me that i know what i putting i my code and for the next time..

Comment: is an example of a display: table - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do it:

Basically making the input transparent, giving color to the form element and positioning the button absolutely over it. Note the position:relative on the form element, as position:absolute is always relative to the closest explicitly relative positioned parent.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
form {
  background-color: #23507c;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
}
form input {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
form button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!-- FontAwesome for icons -->
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- relevant code -->
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
   <input type="text" class="search" name="search" placeholder="search for diamonds" />
   <button type="submit" id="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: hey, i try your code, first i wanted the input width will be up to the button, seconds, i try to delete the button height and give him a padding, but he cut, why?

Comment: @NatiVaknin i don't understand what you mean by 'cut'. Here's a version with padding on the button and 100% input width: https://jsfiddle.net/ehej4g8v/